# How to find decoding length of RLE encoded string

Tags: java, string, decode, decoding

I'm new to stack overflow so I apologize if I lack certain mannerisms. I am working with java right now and am currently trying to find the length of a string when it is decoded from an RLE format. For example, the length of "20A6B2C" will be 28 (20+6+2.) I have found out how to identify individual digits in the string to print "2062" but can't identify how to group "20" into one digit or how to add all of the digits as they are. My current code is as follows. Thanks! (I apologize but I'm VERY new to coding in general.)

```
public class RLEtrial {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String rleString = "20A6B2C";

    if (rleString == null || rleString.isEmpty()) System.out.print("");

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    boolean found = false;
    int findDecodeLength = 0;
    for (char c : rleString.toCharArray()) {
        if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
            sb.append(c);
            found = true;
        }
    }
    System.out.print(sb.toString());
}
```

}

Comment: What happens in this "encoding" if the character to repeat is a digit?

Answer (score 0):

You need Regular expression . `\\d` is used for finding digits; `+` sign is [repetition](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) operator in this case.

```
String DIGIT_REGEX = "\\d+"; // minimum 1 digit number
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(DIGIT_REGEX);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("20A6B2C");
int count = 0;
while(matcher.find()) 
    count += Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(0)); // group 0 is entire pattern (in this case entire number)

System.out.println(count);
```

Comment: I'm sorry but can you explain the Pattern and Matcher functions?

Comment: @MissyAggravation From Oracle Java Doc :

"A compiled representation of a regular expression. A regular expression, specified as a string, must first be compiled into an instance of this class. The resulting pattern can then be used to create a Matcher object that can match arbitrary character sequences against the regular expression."


see this [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)